# "sudo" session behavior in graphical environment

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, gksudo

I wrote these two scripts and they are in my `$PATH`:

**gsudo**:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo -n true &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  sudo "$@"
else
  upass=$(zenity --password --title "Enter your password" 2> /dev/null)
  [[ ! -z "$upass" ]] && echo $upass | sudo -S -p "" "$@"
fi
```

This script essentially does the same thing what `gksu` does. It looks if `sudo` needs password or not and according to the result of that it will ask password or not.

**run-something**:

```
gsudo command1
gsudo command2
```

If I run the second script from a terminal window, I get the expected behavior. It simply asks for my password only one time. But if I call it from a graphical environment, like a task runner(I tried i3wm dmenu and rofi launcher) it asks for my password two times. So why is this happening, how can I fix it? I believe `sudo -n true` should return the same thing both times, because it's getting called in same script so `sudo` session should persist. I'm not trying to save `sudo` session between different script calls, it's enough that it persists only in one call.

Comment: Have you considered using $SUDO_ASKPASS for this?

Comment: @grawity Yes but still same thing happens. I thought this one is maybe more close to solution.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Oh, thanks. I overlooked that. The post is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests. It's not (yet) completely clear to me how `sudo` caches one's ability to elevate. Probably it has something to do with pseudoterminal being allocated or not.

If I were you I would implement what you can read in this question: [*How do I run a `sudo` command inside a script?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/425754/693277) Especially from [one of the answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/425990/693277):

> It is rarely a good idea to have `sudo` inside scripts. Instead, remove the `sudo` from the script and run the script itself with `sudo`

except in your case it's your `gsudo` we're talking about. Additionally I would use `$SUDO_USER`, if necessary (from [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/970898/693277)).

Example `run-something`:

```
#!/path/to/my/gsudo /bin/bash

# The shebang ensures the below code is for sure run with gsudo bash;
# gsudo runs sudo, which sets $SUDO_USER (see `man sudo').

command1   # This is run with gsudo because the entire script is.

# Get back to the invoking (possibly regular) user for just one command
sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" command_whatever

# Again as root
command2
command3

# Get back to the invoking user for many commands
sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" bash << EOF

foo
bar
baz

EOF
```

My `gsudo` would be very simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
SUDO_ASKPASS='/path/to/my/gsudo_helper' sudo "$@"
```

And `gsudo_helper`:

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --password --title "Enter your password" 2> /dev/null
```

Notes:

- I deliberately don't use `sudo -A` in `gsudo` code. This way `gsudo` uses a terminal if available, `zenity` otherwise.
- The syntax `sudo "$@"` allows `gsudo` to pass command line options (like the mentioned `-A`) to `sudo`. This is rather a good idea but if you don't want it then consider `sudo -- "$@"`.

Comment: That shebang pretty much solves my problem. I couldn't think of something like this. Because I was trying to call `run-something` from a GUI, I needed one more level of indirection, like another script calling `gsudo run-something` to call the script itself with `gsudo`.